# Android SQLiteException: am I blind?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have the following exception in my logcat

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table subsectionTable(id2 integer primary key autoincrement,line text not null,from text not null,to text not null);
```

I am to blind to find the problem.

This is my create String:

```
private static final String SUBSECTION_CREATE_STATEMENT = "create table " + TABLE_SUBSECTIONS
            + "(" + COLUMN_ID2 + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + COLUMN_LINE + " text not null,"
            + COLUMN_FROM + " text not null,"
            + COLUMN_TO + " text not null);";
```

Can you help me to find the wrong entry?

Best regards, 
Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from` is a keyword in SQLITE. You are trying to name your column `COLUMN_FROM` as `from`. Use a different name for that column. Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `from` keyword as your field's name. Rename it and it should be fine then.